# Ubuntu Touch - Drop down calendar view

Tags: ubuntu-touch, calendar

With the new geeat looking calendar view from the top dropdown menu. How can I get the days to be highlight that have the events listed below the calendar?

At the moment the current day is highlighted, but I would lile thhave the days that have eventa highlighted too.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get the drop-down calendar to highlight the days with events.

But you can submit a request for such functionality [over here](http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-calendar-app/+filebug?no_redirect)... The Development Team may or may not add it, but posting this request will bring the idea to the attention of other users for discussion and debate.

By the way, you can find a guide to the bug-report/feature request pages for all of the "default" Ubuntu (Touch) components and applications [over here](http://wiki.ubuntu.com/Avengers) - if you find bugs or have suggestions, that's the place to do it (a major bug with the integrated VPN client was fixed because I reported it there, for example).

By the way for anyone wondering, this is what Phil is referring to, accessed by "pulling-down" from the clock (it took me a second to realize what he was talking about):
[image: Drop-down calendar introduced with OTA-12]

Comment: Oh for sure, i have already raised a few bugs so far in Launchpad. I was just wondering if i was missing a setting. I have logged this in Launchpad under Bug #1613525

Comment: Also another great feature would be if the next 5 eventa at the bottom of the calendar chqnge when you swipe from month to month. That will be another one i will raise.

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-calendar-app/+bug/1613525